# Handling search/filtering on a table nested within a data iterated card with Vue.js and Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Trying to search for data on the TDs of the `v-data-table` and then return the `v-card`s with their `v-data-table`s that have matching data to the search value. This becomes difficult because of the nested iterator/table structure.

I have tried to leverage the search function of the `v-data-iterator` and within the `v-data-table`. Have also tried (but failed) to create some sort of custom search function that would return a `Boolean` that could be used to hide the `v-card`s that don't have matching data to the search criteria. Ideally, this would work as a real-time search that would match on each character until it did not match... i.e. = `search='ab'` (still typing) would match on a td customer name "abe" and a business site of "abalone" but would not match if the user typed `search='abc'` and would not return any `v-card`s

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/jbaldwin3/pen/ZEEqYjP?editors=1111)

```
      <v-layout>
        <v-flex xs8 offset-xs2>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="search"
            append-icon="search"
            label="Filter Results"
            single-line
            hide-details
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      <v-data-iterator
        :items="customerSearchArray"
        :rows-per-page-items="[10]"
        content-tag="v-layout"
        row
        wrap
      >
        <template v-slot:item="props">
          <v-flex
            pa-1
            xs12
          >
            <v-card :color="props.index % 2 ? 'rgba(31,150,186, 0.2)' : 'white'"
              :item-key="props.item.associatedCustomerRecords"
            >
              <v-card-title><h4>{{props.index + 1}}). {{ props.item.customerName.firstName + ' ' + props.item.customerName.lastName }}</h4></v-card-title>
              <v-divider></v-divider>
              <v-card-text>
                <v-data-table :headers="headers"
                  class="customer-search-results-table"
                  :items="props.item.associatedCustomerRecords"
                  hide-actions
                >
                  <template v-slot:items="props">
                    TDs to be filtered/searched here....
                  </template>...
```

Comment: can you provide running code? jsfiddle, codepen, inline?

Comment: @Daniel - https://codepen.io/jbaldwin3/pen/ZEEqYjP?editors=1111

Comment: you might need to optimize the array into something that the v-data-table can handle (using computed?). Alternatively, implement your own search on the dataset you're passing to the v-data-table